# What design pattern is Codeigniter using?

Tags: php, design-patterns, codeigniter

Fairly straightforward question:

I know that Codeigniter is a MVC framework - however what design pattern is Codeigniter using?

From first look it seems like Facade, but I could be wrong.

Edit:

Perhaps I should describe Codeigniter for those who don't use it.
In Codeigniter you have a concept of a Controller and a Model, which each has their own separate folder. In each of the folders you create a file:
cart.php:

```
<?php

class Cart {
 //...
}
?>
```

Then you can also have a model:

```
<?php

class User {
    function login(){...}
}
?>
```

Inside of the class Cart, you can use the login function in User by simply using $this->user->login()

I find this interesting because the framework makes an object of the User object and the programmer does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In Codeigniter you have a concept of a
>   Controller and a Model, which each has
>   their own separate folder.

They have setup their main **router** class such that it searches for corresponding controller and model files, it can even go recursive. This has nothing to do with any design pattern, it is just a folder organization.

> I find this interesting because the
>   framework makes an object of the User
>   object and the programmer does not.

Yup, they have created a lot of stuff ready-made and to be used any time you want. The **User** class is used to control whole user system.

*Basically*, as you said, the main design pattern used is MVC, rest of the things are controlled by different *core* classes for a specific task.

Comment: I would stamp MVC on Codeigniter also - but I don't see listed on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science) - which I think it should. Though I still think it is modeled a little after Facade because instead of having $user->login() you have a single class that has basically subclasses...which just happens to be the calling class.